# Debug right to write in USB file (link with udev?)

Tags: drivers, usb, udev

When I try to run the driver [created by Veikk](https://www.veikk.com/support/download.html) for its graphical tablet in sudo mode, the tablet is recognized, however if I run it as a normal user the tablet is not recognized anymore. However, I do have an udev file `20-vktablet.rules` containing:

```
KERNEL=="uinput",MODE:="0666",OPTIONS+="static_node=uinput"
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb",ATTRS{idVendor}=="2feb",MODE:="0666"
```

which seems to be consistent with `lsusb` (as far as I understand):

```
Bus 001 Device 028: ID 2feb:0002 Beijing Veikk E-Commerce Co., Ltd. A30
```

To debug this, I tried to run strace with both `sudo` and as a normal user. The output is huge, but I managed to spot using `git diff` a suspicious line:

```
# For the sudo version:
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/bus/usb/001/028", O_RDWR|O_CLOEXEC) = 17
# For the normal version
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/bus/usb/001/028", O_RDWR|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
```

Do you know what could be wrong? Or any idea how I could debug this further?

**EDIT**

I tried to apply the proposed modifications (who, so much typo for an official driver ^^'), but this is still not enough apparently… Here is the current version:

```
KERNEL=="uinput",MODE="666",OPTIONS+="static_node=uinput"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb",ATTR{idVendor}=="2feb",MODE="666"
```

```
$ ls -al /dev/bus/usb/001/002 
crw-rw-r-- 1 root root 189, 1 avril 19 23:04 /dev/bus/usb/001/002
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I understand my mistake: basically, in NixOs it seems that putting the udev rules in the `$out/lib/udev/rules.d/` folder is not enough: one also install the package using `services.udev.packages = [ mypackage ]`. Then, rebuild, unplug/replug, and enjoy!

Sorry for the noise.